# y axis inversion on pdfTron

Tags: php, pdftron

I got a problem with usage of PDFTron on the back-end ( PHP ) vs frontend.

I have a front end that allow user to define formFields emplacement. When Field is set, we call backend to put them in database and when the document is validated by user, we launch a treatment on back-end to field the pdf binary with the formField.

We do something like that :

```
// Open PDF file with PDFTron
        $doc = new \PDFDoc($temporaryFileName);
        $doc->InitSecurityHandler();

        // get first page by default
        $page = $doc->getPage(1);

        $rect = new \Rect($x1FromFront, $y1FromFront, $x2FromFront, $y2FromFront);

        // Create a new signature field
        $widgetAnnot = \SignatureWidget::Create($doc, $rect, 'Ressource_Stamp');
        $page->AnnotPushBack($widgetAnnot);

        // save documents
        $doc->Save($temporaryFileName, \SDFDoc::e_linearized);
        $doc->Close();
```

But we have a problem, indeed, the y axis on front seems to be not on same order than back-end axis.

If I have "75" for the y1 value on front, the field is displayed on top,
But when I apply the signWidget with backend with "75" for y1, the field is displayed has bottom.

It seems that the 0,0 of axys is "top-left" in front and "top-bottom" on back-end:

Annotation Rect on front : https://www.pdftron.com/api/web/Core.Annotations.Annotation.html#getRect : https://www.pdftron.com/api/web/Core.Math.Rect.html ==> Upper-left

Rect on BackEnd : https://www.pdftron.com/api/web/Core.PDFNet.Rect.html#main ==> lower-left.

Is there a way to inverse the y axis to get always same coordinate between front and PHP ?
Or do we need to compute the y value from the page Height ?

Comment: "I have a front end that allow user to define formFields emplacement." What exactly is the front end? A PDFTron product like WebViewer? Note that PDF pages can actually be rotated, and displaced/offset, from the origin, so getting a general solution might be more complicated than just fllipping the y-aixs. But you would need to make it a lot clearer what the front end source of the Rect is.

Comment: The front-end source is the PDFTron Webviewer : https://www.pdftron.com/api/web/index.html.

Comment: Then the exact same Annotation Rect will work both on the front end and back end for the Same PDF file. The annotations from WebViewer are exported as XFDF XML which is defined in the PDF ISO standard. If you are seeing a difference between front end and back end then the PDF file itself is different between the two. Are you generating the PDF file twice (once in the FE and once in the BE)? If so, how exactly are you doing it on the BE?

Comment: I do not have thé xfdf generated on front end. I only register in database the rect x and y coorodnate given by front-end.   Then when the pdf si validate by user ( After potentially many change) i create thé xfdf by adding annotations on forme with the backend

Comment: Is there a particular reason you are not storing Annotations the official way? https://www.pdftron.com/documentation/web/guides/annotation/import-export/overview/ Otherwise you are going to run into other issues than just this one issue trying to do it your own way. There is more to annotations than just the x/y position.